# Check if a String is HTML or XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Is there a way to check if a String is HTML or XML in JavaScript? Preferably using jQuery rather than some other library?
Why I need to do this is because I need to know if it possible to have a function into which XML or HTML can be passed. If it is HTML we take one action and if it is XML we take another action.

Comment: What if it's HTML that's also well-formed XML (which is also known as XHTML)? Or are you just checking if it's either one and you don't need to know which it is?

Comment: @BoltClock - I took it to mean "if a string is HTML OR XML" as in, it doesn't matter which. But I may be wrong :)

Comment: Do you want to check if the string is a complete, valid representation of an HTML document, or a well-formed XML document? What about XHTML, which is HTML as well-formed XML? Or do you just want to know if a string could be a valid HTML or XML fragment?

Comment: @BoltClock,@James,@kojiro Sorry for the ambiguity. I added some more dtail.

Comment: not reliable but try
if( str.indexOf('<') == -1 || str.indexOf('>') == -1 ) {
   //its html :|
}

Comment: @AamirAfridi What? If it doesn't find `<` or `>` then it's HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if a String is HTML or XML in JavaScript?

Not reliably. You can test for one (e.g. against a DTD or XSD) and if it fails, assume it's the other. However, those tests are meant to be run on entire documents with a valid DOCTYPE. There are many cases where a snippet of markup will pass validation for multiple markup languages. What then?

I think you need to explain *why* you need to know the difference.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question until the author defines whether "Is HTML" means ***valid HTML*** or ***looks like HTML*** (And even then, define at what point something does or doesn't look like HTML).

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that if it starts with <?xml version="1.0"> then it's XML-based. If it doesn't have it, it should NOT be considered XML as XML requires that particular tag.

"An XML file or stream is made up of the following structures:
One or more Processing directives, the most common **being the required <?xml version="1.0">**"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

The brute-force method is to have a list of all the valid html elements and if it isn't one of those then it must be xml.  This may be the cleanest approach.

If you use a namespace for the html then the xml will probably be in a default namespace, so if you look for this line (*Implementing a default namespace for XML documents*) on this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) you will see that anything in the default namespace will return null when using an `XPath` evaluation.

According to this page (http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/04/xpath-in-javascript-part-3/), xpath doesn't work on HTML elements, which would be another way to tell xml from html.

I haven't used xpath, but the implementation may differ among different browsers, according to this page: http://www.yaldex.com/ajax-tutorial-4/BBL0029.html, as Firefox may allow xpath to work on html elements.

So, xpath may be a good solution, depending on browsers supported and whether your xml may use a namespace, but since the number of elements supported in html is finite it would seem that looking within that group would be the most precise solution.

Comment: It may be exceptionally hard to get a valid list of all HTML5 elements with that spec being unstable. The only way would be to get it from some web service, but by the time you do that, you might as well just use the [fragment validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: Kojiro - +1, but the fragment validator will only check for HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0. Many HTML fragments will validate as both. Might as well just set the innerHTML property of a DIV within *try..catch* and see what happens. :-)